# Is there any difference between the following two forms?

Tags: negation, do-support

I'm reading right now a paper related to the state of Hybrid Electric Vehicle (HEV) and Battery Electric Vehicle (BEV) and I saw:

> *BEVs produce no pollutants such as particulates, (...)*

What is the difference between this form and the use of: *BEVs don't produce pollutants such as particulates, (...)*

As far as I know, It's very common to use the first form in papers or textbooks. Why? Is it about formality, rule of scientific papers or something related to grammar figures?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

For people whose native language is not English, reading contractions such as "don't" "hasn't", and so can be difficult. That's why some publishers tell editors to remove the contractions and spell them out. It depends entirely on the journal publisher.